# Spring Boot Cache Providers

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have a Spring Boot application. We load in some data from files that only changes a few times a year. It seems like a good idea to cache this but there seems to be a large selection of Cache Providers and I'm not sure what one is the best fit for our need?

Right now I'm using Caffeine.

Comment: This question is asking for recommendations, which is not what questions are for. Instead of giving out answers with opinions, the asker is free to evaluate the options and compare how well they fulfill the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only running spring-boot as a single instance , `Caffeine` is a good choice which they claim it has a [better performance](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks) than `Guava Cache` and `Ehcache` etc.

One of the downsides is that Caffeine is only a local cache which means if you are running an active-active HA or highly scalable environment which have multiple spring boot instances processing requests at the same time , you have to consider how to tell all instances to update their cache if you update the cached data. Otherwise, you will end up some instance still caching the old data since their cache is not updated yet.

You can evaluate if using distributed cache such as `Hazelcast`, `EhCache` or `Infinispan` etc. will be more easier to replicate the changes to all instances..

Comment: For distributed can we use redis?

Answer (score 0):

just try to use Spring `@Cacheable` annotation.

eg:

```
    @Component
public class Service{

    @Cacheable("files")
    public List<String> getContentFromFile(....) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

The engine which I recommend is `Ehcache` (There is an out of the box Spring Caching integration).